# Bluemix Push service security concern

Tags: ios, security, sdk, push-notification, ibm-cloud

We are using IBM Push-Notification service and Mobile-App-Security on our Bluemix app (serving iOS clients).

In order to send a push notification, our server sends a POST request to: `https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/push/v1/apps/{application-id}/messages`

with the application secret in the Ibm-Application-Secret header (following the instructions [here](https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/mbaas-api/#!/push)).

To initialize Mobile-App-Security SDK inside our app you need both the application-id and the application-secret - this means that the app itself must contain these values (as constant parameters or download it from a server). If a malicious user fetches these values using simple reverse-engineering, he would be able to send the same POST requests, i.e. send push notifications to other clients, right?

Shouldn't there be two application-secrets? One secret for the app (making it hard to fake registrations - i.e. require reverse-engineering) and one for the server (which allows to send notifications and should never be stored on client-side).

Is it possible to initialize the Mobile-App-Security iOS SDK without an application secret?

Comment: Is it possible to send notifications using the Push service without initializing the SDK on the iOS client side?

Comment: No, the SDK is necessary in order to register your device with the Bluemix push service.

Comment: And you have to save the application secret on the device at some point? The same application secret that is used to send push notifications?

Comment: Is this a known issue? @DaveCariello

Comment: Is it possible to limit the access to `https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/push/v1/apps/{application-id}/messages` (and the other apis) with some additional secret key?

Comment: Is the push service suppose to serve only in-house apps where this issue doesn't matter? i.e. only trusty clients can download the app. @JeffSloyer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your concern. To address all your questions:
-You must have the app secret on the Client side in order to authenticate with MAS and use the Push service (Push relies on MAS auth)
-We recommend implementing your own form of security to prevent a malicious user from easily obtaining the App Secret. For example, encrypting  the file that stores the app secret, or just the app secret itself.

If you are looking for a more robust built-in level of security, I would recommend using the newer MobileFirst Services Starter, with support for Push and the Advanced Mobile Access service (AMA), which is currently only available for iOS 8.

Answer (score -1):

A mobile device registers with its unique device id at the server running on Bluemix. If you don't trust a device, you could send a push notification with a key to this device and request it back. If you get this key back, the device has also registered at Google or Apple successfully.

Comment: The application-secret allows to do many operations in the api at https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/mbaas-api : get\set the apns certificate, create tags, get analytics, etc. If the application-secret sits on the client side then it should not be considered a secret! (even if it can be revoked...). This is a major security flaw. The problem is not sending push-notifications to untrusted devices. The problem is that one untrusted device could fetch the application-secret and send spam notifications to all the other devices (or mess things up really bad).

Comment: To add, it is never a good idea to send sensitive or critical data via push notification. Not only is apple able to view that data, but the notifications are delivered on a best-effort basis. They are never guaranteed.